# EF Core is attempting to update a record that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

UPDATE: There was code that I did not see that until after I created this post that was causing my insert to fail. All works as expected now. Apologies, and thank you for the time spent helping.

I am having an issue where EF is attempting to update a record that doesn't exist. I need the record to be inserted.

Sample code below:

```
DoStuff(List<ParentObj> listParent, List<OtherParent> listOtherParent)
{
    foreach(var op in otherParent)
    {
        var updateThisParentRecord = listParent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == op.Id);
        if(updateThisParentRecord != null)
        {
            updateThisParentRecord.ChildRecordList.Add(new ChildRecord
            {
                //set relevant props not PK as it is an identity column
                OtherChildObject = new OtherChildObject 
                {
                    //set relevant props not PK as it is an identity column
                }
            });
        }
    }
    await _parentObjectContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Model code:

```
public partial class ParentObj
{
    public ParentObj()
    {
        ChiledRecordList = new HashSet<ChildRecord>();
    }

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ChildRecord> ChildRecordList {get;set;}
}

public partial class ChildRecord
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public int OtherChildObject {get;set;}

    public virtual OtherChildObject OtherChildObject {get;set;}
    public virtual ParentObj {get;set;}
}

public partial class OtherChildObject
{
    public OtherChildObj()
    {
        ParentObj = new HashSet<ParentObj>();
        ChildRecord = new Hashset<ChildRecord>();
    }

    public long Id {get;set;}
    //now that I have written this out, the below line seems strange and may 
    //be keyed wrong?
    public virtual ICollection<ParentObj> ParentObj {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ChildRecord> ChildRecord {get;set;}
}
```

When saving the below exception is thrown:

"Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).
Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."

This is what is in the entry list of the exception: {{Id: 1000} Modified EntityType: ChildRecord}

The generated SQL from EF rightfully creates OtherChildObject but it is attempting to update the ChildRecord which doesn't exist. Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks in advance

Comment: People are going to want to see your model code

Comment: Updated with model code

Comment: What are you actually setting in the "//set relevant props not PK as it is an identity column" parts?

Comment: I need to add an update here. There was some other nefarious code that has never had a thread run through it that was doing something silly that I did not notice until I realized that I kept stepping over a method that I thought had been QC'ed before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking change from [DetectChanges honors store-generated key values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#detectchanges-honors-store-generated-key-values):

> Old behavior
>
> Before EF Core 3.0, an untracked entity found by DetectChanges would
> be tracked in the Added state and inserted as a new row when
> SaveChanges is called.
>
> New behavior
>
> Starting with EF Core 3.0, if an entity is using generated key values
> and some key value is set, then the entity will be tracked in the
> Modified state. This means that a row for the entity is assumed to
> exist and it will be updated when SaveChanges is called. If the key
> value isn't set, or if the entity type isn't using generated keys,
> then the new entity will still be tracked as Added as in previous
> versions.
>
> Why
>
> This change was made to make it easier and more consistent to work
> with disconnected entity graphs while using store-generated keys.
>
> Mitigations
>
> This change can break an application if an entity type is configured
> to use generated keys but key values are explicitly set for new
> instances. The fix is to explicitly configure the key properties to
> not use generated values. For example, with the fluent API:
>
> ```
> modelBuilder
>     .Entity<Blog>()
>     .Property(e => e.Id)
>     .ValueGeneratedNever();
> ```
>
> Or with data annotations:
>
> ```
> [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
> public string Id { get; set; }
> ```

If you are explicitly setting the Id of your ChildObjects and the entity is using generated key values then they will be tracked in the Modified state.

Comment: Whenever I make the suggested changes I receive this error:
{"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ChildRecord' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

Comment: What was your initial configuration for the PK property? [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] or rather .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()?

Comment: There weren't any of those annotations or methods on the original model builder or entity

I ended up trying both independently both resulted in the same error.

Comment: It seems to be a dilemma, you want the Id to be generated but it is not allowed in your example. Only solution is to add the ChildRecords individually and not via the ParentRecord.

Comment: That is the direction I am starting to go in. It just feels dirty and wrong

Comment: Did you actually set the ParentId? Then that might have caused the problem.

Comment: No, my code was fine. This is a project shared among a pretty big team. I added an update to the question. There was some code that I kept stepping over assuming that it was QC'ed since it has been in the app for awhile but it has never met the condition to cause it to fail until I started working in that area. The offending code was in fact setting the Id of a new object. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Ok but then I have to correct my assumption in the answer. If you or someone didn't set the Id explicitly everything would have worked.

Comment: This is a very tough one to debug. It took me an hour to realize what was even happening.